# Eliminate group of NULLs from result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns a result set similar to the one below:

```
   Quarter  | Count
   -------  | -----
1   Q2 2009 | NULL
2   Q2 2009 | NULL
3   Q2 2009 | NULL
4   Q3 2009 | 26
5   Q3 2009 | 27
6   Q3 2009 | NULL
```

I don't want rows 1-3, because their combined Quarter-Count is NULL.  But I do want rows 3-6 because at least one Count from the same Quarter is not NULL.

How do I come from the result set above to this one:

```
   Quarter  | Count
   -------  | -----
1   Q3 2009 | 26
2   Q3 2009 | 27
3   Q3 2009 | NULL
```

Thanks.

Comment: are rows 1- 3 meant to be Q1 2009?

Comment: I'll try to help you adjust your query, if you'll show me your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Quarter, Count
FROM
    MyTable M
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM MyTable m2
        WHERE m2.Count IS NOT NULL AND m.Quarter = m2.Quarter)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable mo
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.quarter = mo.quarter
                AND mi.count IS NOT NULL
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that aggregate functions ignore null and do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable m1 inner join 
(
SELECT quarter as q2 from myTable 
GROUP BY quarter
HAVING sum(count) is not null
) as m2 on m1.quarter = m2.q2
```

Which might have a better execution plan than an EXISTS - it might not.